# struct coding style in c++ header

Tags: c++, struct, header

I have some example codes that will be delivered to customers for generating their own embedded codes. As you can imagine, we have some predefined structs defined in the header files. For example:

```
typedef struct MEMORY_S {
  uint64_t phyAddr;
  void *virAddr;
  size_t memSize;
} B_MEMORY_S;

typedef struct DATA_SHAPE_S {
  B_MEMORY_S memory;
  int ndim;
  int d[MAX_SHAPE_DIM];  
} B_DATA_SHAPE_S;
```

As you can see, these structs are nested and getting their value can be a hassle. I would like to define toString() function within the struct. Like showing below.

```
typedef struct DATA_SHAPE_S {
  B_MEMORY_S memory;
  int ndim;
  int d[MAX_SHAPE_DIM];  

  std::string toString() {
    std::string res = "";
    res += "layout: " + std::to_string(this->layout) + "   ";
    res += "ndim: " + std::to_string(this->ndim) + "   ";
    res += "d: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < this->ndim - 1; i++) {
      res += std::to_string(this->d[i]) + "x";
    }
    res += std::to_string(this->d[ndim - 1]);
    return res;
  }
} B_DATA_SHAPE_S;
```

My teammates think it is not a good idea to add functions in the header file. I'd like to hear some opinions and see what is the professional way of solving such problems.

Comment: Why your "... teammates think it is not a good idea to add functions in the header file"? Are there arguments? Maybe you may not expose the implementation details to the customers?

Comment: BTW, could be `const` and possibly free function instead of member function.

Comment: That's rather opinion-based. IMO, this function is too long to justify inline definition, it should be moved to a .cpp file. Also, your structs seem to be prepared for interfacing with C - adding a method would disqualify that.

Comment: The `typedef struct Name1 {} Name2;` formula is a C-ism, so I would assume that your customers are expecting to use these in C (which would make your suggestion a definite "no"). If they're not doing that, `struct Name {};` is the idiomatic C++ form.

Comment: Not enough context for a proper answer. Imposing `<string>` to customers means having dynamic allocations and related exceptions, that may be acceptable or not depending on the application requirements. Moreover, adding a method imposes to customers an object-oriented design when they may prefer a data-oriented one.